# In Gremlin, there is a query error when converting TinerGraph to JanusGraph?

Tags: .net, database, gremlin, janusgraph, tinkergraph

I have a code like the one below. Since I switched TinkerGraph to JanusGraph it got an error:

> Gremlin.Net System.InvalidOperationException: 'Deserializer for “janusgraph:RelationIdentifier” not found' exception

```
var result =
    _g.V().BothE("name").OtherV().Path().By(__.ValueMap<object, object>(true)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common serializer error and likely related to an error on your client side. The `RelationIdentifier` is a JanusGraph specific class (i.e. an `Edge` identifier) and therefore the TinkerPop drivers don't know how to process it. Either avoid JanusGraph specific classes by not returing the `Edge` `T.id` in `valueMap()` or consider using [janusgraph-dotnet](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-dotnet).

Comment: I used, but still failed, and installed JanusGraph.net:
var employee = _g.V (idEmployee) .HasLabel (Employee.Label)
                    .InE (Employee.LabelEdgeRole)
                    .OtherV ()
                    .Path ()
                    .By (__. ValueMap <object, object> (true));

             var result = await employee.Promise (t => t.ToList ());

Comment: But it is  erro: Gremlin.Net System.InvalidOperationException: 'Deserializer for “janusgraph:RelationIdentifier” not found' exception

Comment: remove the `true` from `valueMap()` so that the `RelationId` is not returned. even if you need that id, it would be good to just see that you've isolated the serialization error to that, though your error in the comment above seems to be clear that it is. if you don't need the id/label then i sense you have your solution. Note that janusgraph-dotnet does have the `RelationIdentifier` deserializer in their code so its curious that you're not finding this workign: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-dotnet/blob/master/src/JanusGraph.Net/IO/GraphSON/RelationIdentifierDeserializer.cs

Comment: I am a student intern, I am investigating the gremlin. I don't understand it very well. Glad if you write a query snippet with my above query along with: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-dotnet/blob/master/src/JanusGraph.Net/IO/GraphSON/RelationIdentifierDeserializer.cs .... so it won't fail

Comment: I need the edge id and label

Comment: How did you create the client? Did you use the `JanusGraphClientBuilder` as described in [the README.md of JanusGraph.Net](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-dotnet#usage)? If you did, then the needed serializers are already registered by default and it should just work.